# Convert to SEO friendly URL

Tags: .htaccess, seo

I'm trying to make my website URLs SEO-friendly, and I'm having problems...

How can I change this URL:

http://www.example.com/media.php?album=Album_1&page=1

To this kind of URL:

http://www.example.com/media/Album_1/1

I've tried this code that works, but my CSS seems KO...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^media/(.*?)/([0-9]+)$ media.php?album=$1&amp;page=$2
```

Comment: What do you mean your "CSS seems KO"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule's target doesn't need the `&amp;`, it should just be `&`. Apache will propery encode it as needed (like in the anchor link in the HTML returned in a redirect). The reason your css isn't working sounds like a relative vs absolute URL issue. If your css is linked like `<link rel=stylesheet href="something.css">`, the relative URL resolution ends up being `/media/Album_1/something.css`.

Try adding this in the headers of your pages:

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: Thanks! Made it work correctly with your help, using <base href="/">. The CSS problem was exactly that

Comment: +1 for `<base href="/" />` You learn something new every day!

Answer (score 0):

Try reading mod_rewrite apache documents or just searching 'mod_rewrite' This specific question was asked many times